# Issue setting up xcode 7 on El Capitan osx 10.11 and python

Tags: python-2.7, xcode7, osx-elcapitan

got a new mac, wanting to setup python and xcode, I am facing two issues.

1. python directory is showing up as "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python" which I think should be "usr/bin/python"...is this correct? if so how do I change it back?
2. I have followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ysik6P5MIVs to setup xcode but when I go to run my simple code, I get a error "There is an problem launching using posix_spawn (error code: 8)." but it also says "build successful". I think this issue is somehow related to #1.

How to setup my computer?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use "/usr/bin/pythonw"

It works!